# Is there a way to write a C preprocessor macro with variable args like this?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want a C preprocessor macro that can convert this:

```
if (IN(node->type, BRANCH, CAPTURE_START, CAPTURE_END)) {
    ...
}
```

to this:

```
if (node->type == BRANCH || node->type == CAPTURE_START || node->type == CAPTURE_END) {
    ...
}
```

which is kind of similar to the MySQL IN operator. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you just looking for simple macro substitution to check if the given value is any one of those options? If so can you do just `#define IN(val, opt1, opt2, opt3) (val == opt1 || val == opt2 || val ==opt3)`

Comment: I want that, but with arbitrary numbers of options.

Comment: Not with *arbitrary*. Even for counting macro arguments you need to write a macro or two for each argument count...

Answer (score 0):

CPP does not support iterating over the list of arguments. The closest structure in "C" will be switch statement, but it does not lead itself to

```
  switch (node->type ) {
      case V1:
      case V2:
      case V3:
          ...
   }
```

As an alternative, you can get something that is more inline with the 'IN' test, using a 
A function WITH vararg function. This is limitations that (1) type must be known and (2) there will be a special value (LAST in the example) to indicate the end of the list

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define LAST (-1)

bool in_int_set(int v, ...)
{
   va_list ap ;
   va_start(ap, v) ;
   for (;;) {                        // forever
        int s = va_arg(ap, int) ;
        if ( s == LAST ) return false ;
        if ( s == v ) return true ;
   } ;
}

void main(void) {
        printf("A=%d\n", in_int_set(5,      3, 5, 7, LAST)) ;
        printf("B=%d\n", in_int_set(5,      2, 4, 6, 8, 10, LAST)) ;
// From the question about
        if ( in_int_set(node->type,     BRANCH, CAPTURE_START, CAPTURE_END, LAST) ) {
            ...
        }
}
```